# PhoneGap Application with HTML5

Tags: html, cordova

I am building a website which will be then converted into mobile app using PhoneGap for 3 OSs (iOS, Android & Windows Phone). The structure of my web page is such that it is having 3 vertical DIVs. I have controlled the width of these DIVs using Media-Queries and it is working fine on both desktop & Android Emulator. This means on Desktop all the three DIVs will show simultaneously but on mobile App I want to show only one DIV at a time and when user scroll the screen horizontally using touch then second DIV will be shown on the mobile screen and similarly the third DIV on further scrolling using touch. In short I want each DIV to be a page on mobile app.

But it is showing all the three divs on the main screen. I want to know that how I will control my web page that when it is viewed on desktop all the three DIVs will show simultaneously and when it is viewed on mobile using PhoneGap Application only one div will be visible to user at a time.

hope I am clear to you. I am also pasting the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />   
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="CommonFunctions.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-with, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topContainer" class="container">
        <div id="topSectionHeating" class="topSectionHeating">          
            DIV1
        </div>

        <div id="topSectionHotWater" class="topSectionHotWater">            
            DIV2
        </div>

        <div id="topSectionSchedule"  class="topSectionSchedule">       
            DIV3
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery? You can assign a onClick() to buttons and accordingly show/ hide div's.

If you aren't familiar with jQuery, start off [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp) or some good tutorials are provided [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Comment: Thanks Keshav. I have found a workaround to do this using Media Queries only. Will you please tell me about ow to implement the swipe event in the HTML5 using jQuery Mobile. Or provide me some useful links on this.

Comment: jQuery mobile has got extensive documentation. [Here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) is the swipe event you are looking for.